# Can't place breakpoints in Visual Studio Code with Debugger for Chrome

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am simply trying to debug some javascript that is within my html page.

I setup the configuration as follows:

but when I am debugging my html page (using the second option called "launch the div.html"), it runs but I can't set breakpoints...

Any ideas?

```html
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch the div.html",            
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/div.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Don't you need the "url" option in your second configuration? Does setting a breakpoint work when you launch the first configuration?

Comment: I don't have a web server running, I am just debugging an html page, so no need for url, I use file...

Comment: I see, sorry. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems debugging inline JavaScript is not supported (I can't set a breakpoint either). You have to separate your JS code into its own file and include it into div.html like so: `<script src="div.js"></script>`
Now set breakpoints in your div.js and start debugging. I encountered problems when I first run debugging that breakpoints were not hit/loaded. I could solve that be clicking on the green "Restart" debug button.

PS: You need the Debugger for Chrome extension to be installed, but it seems you have already done that.

Answer (score 1):

Check again with VSCode 1.39 (Sept. 2019)

It does improve the UI for column breakpoints

> While debugging, VS Code now shows all the breakpoint candidate locations inline.
>   This makes it easier for the user to place a breakpoint on a more accurate position.
>   To not clutter the UI, candidate breakpoints are only shown if there is more than one possible location on the line.
>
> You can interact directly with inline breakpoints; clicking to enable and disable them and invoking their context menu for more actions.

[image: Inline breakpoints: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_39/breakpoints.gif]

> Note that this feature requires support by the underlying runtime or debugger, and we expect only a few debug extensions will use this feature in the future.
>   For this release, Node Debug and the Debugger for Chrome support this.
>   As an example for extension authors, our Mock Debug sample "mocks" support for this.